# Integrate n-dimensional function effectively on boost

Tags: math, boost

Can I integrate n-dimensional function on boost?
I wrote the following code.

```
using boost::math::quadrature::trapezoidal;
return trapezoidal(
  [&](double x) { 
    return trapezoidal([&](double y) {
      return f(x, y); }, b1, e1);
    }, b0, e0);
```

of course, This code is much slower than Python's [scipy.integrate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) that can integrate ND function.
Is there a more efficient implementation?

Thanks.

EDIT: I want to integrate 2 or 3 dimentinon, relatively low dimension. like f(x,y) = sin(x) * sin(y).

Answer (score 0):

By ND I guess you mean n-dimensional. (It's good to spell it out in any case.) You have made a good start. There are at least three ways to go from here.

(1) Replace the trapezoidal rule with a more efficient 1-dimensional rule such as Gaussian integration or Gauss-Kronrod. GK is implemented by the quadpack library which is probably included in Boost or another library.

(2) Look for rules which are derived specifically for multiple dimensions. A web search might find something.

(3) Instead of quadrature methods (essentially integrating polynomial approximations), try methods based on sampling. Take a look at Monte Carlo methods and quasi-Monte Carlo. Quasi-Monte Carlo is kind of intriguing -- it is based on low-discrepancy sequences. Again a web search will find some resources.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks.

Yes, boost has other [quadratures][1] .
My question is, I want to do like scipy.integrate on boost.
Maybe scipy doesn't MC-Sample.

  [1]: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/quadrature.html

Answer (score 0):

Boost does not have multivariate quadratures, other than Monte-Carlo, which is overkill in 2d. The reason things are slow is that trapezoidal quadrature is only efficient for periodic integrands. I assume from your complaint that `f` is neither periodic in `x` nor `y`. Switch out `trapezoidal` for `tanh_sinh`, and things should work better.

Note that in your particular example `f(x,y) = sin(x)*sin(y)`, the integrand is separable, so you don't need to use multivariate quadrature; you can use products of 1d quadratures. (I don't want to nitpick-because I imagine your example is not to be taken too literally, but nonetheless, this is an important optimization if you can use it.)